# Cannot access a disposed object.\r\nObject name: 'DataContext accessed after Dispose'

Tags: entity-framework, dependency-injection, asp.net-web-api2, dbcontext, structuremap3

I am using StructureMap.WebApi2 nuget package for Web API 2 project for managing the depedency injection. 
In the DefaultRegistry.cs class I have mentioned all the dependencies required
Nested container is used for each request.

```
For<IScoreRepository>().Use<ScoreRepository>();
 For<IExternalUsersAuditRepository>().Use<ExternalUsersAuditRepository>();
 For<ITestScanService>().Use<TestScanService>();


 // hook up specific questionnaire datacontext
 For<SportsDataContext>().LifecycleIs(new HttpContextLifecycle())
   .Use(c => new SportsDataContext(
     ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Database"].ConnectionString));

// hook up datacontext for data and services
For<QuestionDataContext>().LifecycleIs(new HttpContextLifecycle())
  .Use(c => new QuestionDataContext(
     ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Database"].ConnectionString));
```

In the previous version of structuremap  HttpContextScoped was available but with the latest version 3.0.0.0 it is no more available hence I have setup LifeCycle as HttpContextLifeCycle.

Linq to Sql Datacontext objects are getting disposed and I get the below error:

> Cannot access a disposed object.\r\nObject name: 'DataContext accessed after Dispose'

If I use `Singleton` or `ThreadLocalStorageLifecycle` scope for the `Datacontext` it's working fine. But I want to scope the `DataContext` objects to Per Http Request.

How can I scope the `Datacontext` object to per Http Request?

I referred the following article  but it is not working for `HttpContextLifeCycle`:

http://ignipro.blogspot.in/2012/09/structuremap-scopes-and-life-cycles.html

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the hosting that you use for your Web API2 the old

From http://structuremap.github.io/object-lifecycle/supported-lifecycles/#aspnet

> The StructureMap team strongly recommends against using the old ASP.Net lifecycles. Most modern web frameworks in .Net will use a Nested Container per request to accomplish the same scoping in a better way.

What you should use is this:

[StructureMap - Nested Containers (Per Request/Transaction)](http://structuremap.github.io/the-container/nested-containers/)

You can read this blog post which explains how to implement it step by step:

[Utilizing Structuremap 3 with ASP.NET MVC](http://www.khalidabuhakmeh.com/utilizing-structuremap-3-with-asp-net-mvc)

The simplest answer is that the Nuget Packages Structuremap.MVC4, Structuremap.MVC5 and Structuremap.WebAPI2 use Structuremap's nested containers.

Comment: Hi Jota..I am using Nesting Containers. Using StructureMap.WebApi2 nuget package. I am having issue with only Linq to Sql DataContext objects with default transient scope. Getting the error "Cannot access a disposed object.\r\nObject name: 'DataContext accessed after Dispose". If I use LifecycleIs<ThreadLocalStorageLifecycle>() it works. But storing datacontext in Thread local storage might cause issues as the datacontext should be created per request. Please suggest. Thanks in advance.

Comment: mmmm, that's strange. Transient lifecycle in a nested context is used to share the same instance of the object for all transient resolutions in the container. The disposing only happens when the nested container is disposed of. The Singleton lifecycle uses the parent container singleton, so it's not disposed. I don't know how the thread local storage is implemented, but I think it uses the parent container. Are you sure your dependency isn't being disposed somewhere else? Why don't you implemente IDisposable in you own DbContext, set a breakpoint and see the stack trace?